# contentComponent: CustomDrawerContentComponent is not working after update to sdk 42

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

I updated my react native application to SDK 42. After that left navigator bar is not working. it only popup and show image only. but if i comment contentComponent: CustomDrawerContentComponent part in the createDrawerNavigator then image disapear and my navigation menus are showing.

**My Code**

```
const CustomDrawerContentComponent = (props) => (
            <ScrollView>
            <Container  style={styles.container}>
                <Header style={styles.drawerHeader}>
                    <Body style={styles.headerBody}>

                    <Image
                    ref={(ref) => this.logoImgRef = ref}
                    style={{ width: 120, height: 120, marginTop:10}}
                    source={imgLogo}
                />
                    </Body>
                </Header>
                <Content>
                    <DrawerItems {...props}/>
                </Content>

            </Container>
            </ScrollView>
        )

        const DrMenu= createDrawerNavigator({

                "Home": {
                    navigationOptions: {
                        drawerIcon: () => (
                            <Icon name='home'
                                  color='#1976D2' size={26}/>
                        ),
                        title: i18n.t('home'),
                    },
                    screen: (props) => <FLHome {...props} propName={FLHome}  {...contactData}  />
                },
               
                "Logout": {
                    navigationOptions: {
                        drawerIcon: () => (
                            <Icon name='sign-out'
                                  color='#1976D2' size={26}/>
                        ),
                        title: i18n.t('logout'),
                    },
                    screen: (props) => <Logout {...props} propName={Logout} />
                },


            }, {
                initialRouteName: "Home",
                drawerPosition: 'left',
                contentComponent: CustomDrawerContentComponent,
                contentOptions: {
                    activeTintColor: '#1976D2',
                    inactiveTintColor :'#1999CE',
                    activeBackgroundColor :'#E8EAF6',
                },
                drawerOpenRoute: 'DrawerOpen',
                drawerCloseRoute: 'DrawerClose',
            }

        );
        
        const App = createAppContainer(DrMenu);
         return(           
                 <App/>
      
         ); 
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

react-native provides functional creation of rendering objects

```
const DateSelect = ()=>{
  return  (<DataSelect/>)
}

export default DateSelect

//import alias
import DateSelection from 'path';

//use
 render.dom
<DateSelection/>
```

Comment: Warning: Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of <Component /> from render. Or maybe you meant to call this function rather than return it. this one is appearing.

Comment: Based on the above warning, the solution I gave, look at my updated code

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution for this problem. That is you have to create another JS page and render in this page like this below,

```
export default CustomDrawerContentComponent = props => (

    <ScrollView>
        <View style={styles.container}>
        <Image 
            source={imgLogo}
            style={{ width: 120, height: 120, marginTop:10}}
            
        />
        </View>
        

        <View>
        <DrawerNavigatorItems {...props}/>
        </View>
    </ScrollView>

);
```

Then you can render in this way in the DrawerViewConfig

```
contentComponent:  props => <CustomDrawerContentComponent {...props} />
```